# conversion of hexa to decimal int 

Tags: javascript

In javascript how the hexadecimal and octal integers are converted to the decimal values:

For example:

```
var num=parseInt("0x10");
 document.write(num);
```

It displays as output the value 16 how??

Comment: what do you expect from the output? `0x10`?

Comment: What is a "hexadecimal integer"?

Answer (score 1):

```
var hexnum = parseInt("0x10", "16"); //for hexadecimal
var octnum = parseInt("10", "8");  //for octal
```

Comment: Maybe you want to leave that `0x` out. The second example only yields `0`

Answer (score 1):

> the hexadecimal and octal integers are converted to the decimal values

No.

No, no, no.

When you do `parseInt` (*passing the base parameter please!*), the number represented in the string input is converted to *binary* for internal representation, and by default outputting a number does so in decimal.

The number, as stored, is neither "decimal" or "octal" at all.

If you want the hexadecimal representation, then print it as such:

```
var num=parseInt("0x10", 16);
document.write(number.toString(16));
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's `parseInt` takes an optional second argument `radix`, specifying which base you want to convert to. From [MDN parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> If radix is undefined or 0, JavaScript assumes the following:
>
> If the input string begins with "0x" or "0X", radix is 16 (hexadecimal).
>
> If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight (octal).
>
> This feature is non-standard, and some implementations deliberately do not support it (instead using the radix 10).  For this reason always specify a radix when using parseInt.
>
> If the input string begins with any other value, the radix is 10 (decimal).

In your case, specifying the `radix` 10

```
var num = parseInt("0x10", 10)
```

yields `num == 0`, while `radix` 16

```
var num = parseInt("0x10", 16)
```

yields `num == 16` (since `0x10` when interpreted as a hexadecimal number equals 16 in decimal (base 10).

It is always good to specify the `radix` you expect to interpret your input in.